# How can I avoid the display of percentage values, when using the ProgressIndicator of JavaFX UI Controls

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I am pretty new to Java and would like get rid of the displayed percentage value of the ProgressIndicator in Java FX. Is there a method to disable the value display? I checked the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html), but as far as I understand it and couldn't find the right method. 
Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Editing the Text value**

Since the `Text` node used for displaying the progress value is hidden in an inner class within the `ProgressIndicatorSkin` class, the best way to access it is using lookups, trying to find this node by its styleclass `percentage`.

This snippet will just remove the `%` character.

```
private Text lookup;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Group root = new Group();
    final ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();

    root.getChildren().add( indicator );
    final Scene scene = new Scene( root );

    final Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {

            IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEach( i ->{
                updateProgress( i, 1000 );
                try{ Thread.sleep(10); } catch(InterruptedException ie){}
            });

            return null;
        }
    };

    indicator.progressProperty().bind( task.progressProperty() );
    new Thread( task ).start();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    indicator.progressProperty().addListener((obs,n,n1)->{
        if(lookup==null){
            lookup= (Text)root.lookup(".percentage");
        }
        lookup.setText(lookup.getText().replace("%", ""));
    });         
}
```

**Removing the Text Value**

A complete different problem is getting rid of the `Text` node.

There's a static `Text` called `doneText` which

> is just used to know the size of done as that is the biggest text we need to allow for

So any change to the `lookup` node won't affect the bounding box of the whole control.

What's more, given that the `Text` node is child of a `Region`, the children list is not modificable.

So the workaround I've come up with is just clipping the indicator.

```
private Text lookup;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final VBox root = new VBox();

    final ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    root.getChildren().addAll( new Group(indicator), new Button("Some Button") );
    final Scene scene = new Scene( root );

    final Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {

            IntStream.range(0, 1_000).forEach( i ->{
                updateProgress( i, 1_000 );
                try{ Thread.sleep(10); } catch(InterruptedException ie){}
            });

            return null;
        }
    };

    indicator.widthProperty().addListener((obs,d,d1)->{
        if(d.doubleValue()>0){
            // Clip the indicator
            Rectangle clip=new Rectangle(d1.doubleValue(),d1.doubleValue());
            indicator.setClip(clip);
        }
    });
    indicator.progressProperty().bind( task.progressProperty() );

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    new Thread( task ).start();

}
```

Now we can layout other controls properly.

[image: clipped indicator]

Comment: In you case Text indicator still using space below circle indicator. `setVisible` and `setManaged` doesn't works because  ProgressIndicatorSkin changing it during re-layout process. Do you have any ideas how to hide Text indicator totally?

Comment: I think I've missread the question... you want to get rid of the text node, and recover its space, right?

Comment: Yes, hide `X%` text and leave used space.

Comment: @Matt95 It does work fine for me. What is the issue? Which JDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by adding padding right to -16....