# Remove label from ProgressIndicator so that it actually resizes 'before start' or 'when done'

Tags: java, css, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying something out with a tiny sized ProgressIndicator but I'm stuck at the moment. The ProgressIndicator gets a INFINITY (-1) progress value as long as the task runs.

As I only want to see the 'spinning wheel' and no text whatsoever in the ProgressIndicator node, I have tried to "remove" the text with CSS:

```
.onlyProgressIndicator .percentage {
    -fx-fill: null;
}
```

However, instead of removing the text, it just hides it (or it might actually remove it but then does not resize the 'spinning wheel'). Because of this, before the task starts and when the task finishes, I get a very very tiny 'wheel'. This is an example of how it looks before the task has started:

[image: tinytinytiny progressindicator wheel]

As you can see, way too tiny :)

While running the task, everything looks ok as the text is actually removed from the ProgressIndicator because of the INFINITE (-1) value. When the task completes, I get the same issue as before the start. Dynamic view of the result:

[image: progressindicator process]

Any idea how I can trigger the resizing when the task has not yet been started or has finished so the wheel is as big as during the call phase?

Or, another approach, if it is possible to bind the text of the progress indicator to the `messageProperty()` of task and move the text of the progress indicator by CSS to the left of the actual spinning wheel, would be even better. However, I did not find a `textProperty()`or `messageProperty()` for a ProgressIndicator.
So for now, I did bind the `textProperty()` of a Label node (wrapped together with the ProgressIndicator in a HBox) to the `messageProperty()` of the task.

```
label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
```

Simplified code of the task:

```
private static Task createJiraIssue(Throwable ex, Map<String, String> map) {
    int max = 1;
    return new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            updateMessage("Set up connection to JIRA...");
            Thread.sleep(2500);
            updateMessage("Fetching issue data...");
            Thread.sleep(2500);
            updateMessage("Create new issue...");
            Thread.sleep(2500);

            updateMessage("Uploading log file...");

            updateProgress(max, max);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded() {
            super.succeeded();
            updateMessage("Bug report send.");
        }

        @Override
        protected void cancelled() {
            super.cancelled();
            updateMessage("Cancelled!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void failed() {
            super.failed();
            updateMessage("Sending bug report failed.");
        }
    };
}

private void runBackgroundTask(){
    Task task = createJiraIssue();

    label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877859/how-can-i-avoid-the-display-of-percentage-values-when-using-the-progressindicat

Comment: Thanks for your response DVarga. I've been trying that already but it does not seem to resize as well. Also, this is a work around and I wondered if there is a cleaner solution to this issue.