# JavaFX: Remove percentage from ProgressIndicator

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I have been trying to remove the percentage text below the ProgressIndicator, but is unsuccessful. I have found several mentions of this and tried the accepted answer, but it does not work

Using Java 8 Update 121

```
package com.company.mytest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProgressApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
        progress.setProgress(0.5f);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(progress);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        scene.getStylesheets()
        .add(getClass().getResource("progress.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX 8 app");
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

I know the CSS is loaded, because I am able to change the percentage font size. This is the CSS content of the progress.css file.

```
.progress-indicator .percentage {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `-fx-fill` attribute to `null` seems solving the problem:

```
.progress-indicator .percentage {
   -fx-fill:null;
}
```

---

**Update:**

Setting only this attribute **hides the percentage text, but still takes up the space.**

A possible workaround is to set the `-fx-padding` attribute of the `ProgressIndicator`:

```
.progress-indicator .percentage {
    -fx-fill:null;
}

.progress-indicator  {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 -16 0;
}
```

The only problem is the hardcoded value: if the CSS for `.progress-indicator .percentage` is changed (e.g. bigger font size) then this also has to be adapted.

---

Alternatively a programatic solution in this answer: [How can I avoid the display of percentage values, when using the ProgressIndicator of JavaFX UI Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877859/how-can-i-avoid-the-display-of-percentage-values-when-using-the-progressindicat)

Comment: Yes, but it still takes up space. Even with setting font-size very small the percentage takes up more space than it uses.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Setting padding did the trick. However setting a hard coded negative value for bottom padding is not ideal. Using the programatic solution could be the better choice, if it does not have any additional overhead on performance.